# Which stability criterion to use for LTI system with Gaussian noise?

Tags: normal-distribution, control-theory, stability-theory, discrete-time

This might (and hopefully will) be a very simple question but I'm quite stumped after doing some research: consider the noise-free discrete-time LTI dynamics given by

$ \boldsymbol{x}(k+1) = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}(k) $

We can easily prove that this system is globally exponentially stable (GES), defined as $\Vert \boldsymbol{x}(k) \Vert \leq c \cdot a^{k} \cdot \Vert \boldsymbol{x}(0) \Vert$ for all $\boldsymbol{x}(0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $0 < c$ and $0< a<1$, which implies $\lim_{k \to \infty} \Vert \boldsymbol{x}(k) \Vert = 0$, if and only if $\boldsymbol{A}$ is Schur stable. Now consider instead

$ \boldsymbol{x}(k+1) = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}(k) + \boldsymbol{E} \boldsymbol{w}(k) $

where $\boldsymbol{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ is i.i.d. Gaussian noise. In that case, the system is no longer GES since it doesn't satisfy the given definition: GES only applies to deterministic systems (correct me if I'm wrong). However, I'm quite lost on which other type of stability criterion I should/could use: for example, do any of (the common definitions of) bounded-input, bounded-output (BIBO) stability, input-to-state stability (ISS), $L_{2}$ stability, $L_{\infty}$ stability, mean squared stability (MSS) and almost surely stable (ASS) apply and if so, where can I find a book/paper proof statings these theorems for simple LTI systems? Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am writing a report on formal methods in control and as such, I am looking for any referrals to books/papers where the definitions of (stochastic) stability, such as MSS, for LTI systems with Gaussian noise (or general noise) are clearly stated and constructive proofs of those definitions for certain types of systems are provided.

I have found several references in regards to bounded disturbances and ISS and $L_p$ stability, but this is specifically not what I am after: what if we know the PDF of the noise but its support could be unbounded?

Comment: You can have a look at the book by van Schuppen, "Control and Systems Theory of Discrete-Time Stochastic Systems".

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to check it out! I couldn't find a publically available copy but I'll see what I can do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of global exponential stability you consider is only really valid for system with inputs or with vanishing ones. When you have a system with inputs, deterministic or not, we consider other types of stability notions which  often imply the GES of the autononous system. In the linear deterministic case, those notions are often equivalent.

For instance, the following statements are equivalent

- The system $x(k+1)=Ax(k)$ is GES,
- The system $x(k+1)=Ax(k)+Ew(k)$, $y(k)=Cx(k)$ is BIBO stable,
- The system $x(k+1)=Ax(k)+Ew(k)$, $y(k)=Cx(k)$ has finite $\ell_2$-gain, and
- The system $x(k+1)=Ax(k)+Ew(k)$, $y(k)=Cx(k)$ has finite $\ell_\infty$-gain

where we have assumed that the system $(A,B,C)$ is both observable and controllable.

Let us go back now to the stochastic system you consider. The additional difficulty now is the randomness but stability can be addressed using moments of the state.

The first-order moment of the state has been already addressed by Kwin van der Veen.

The second order moments can be seen to obey the expression

$$
S(k+1)=AS(k)A^T+E\Sigma E^T
$$
where $S(k)=\mathbb{E}[x(k)x(k)^T]$.

The noise now acts as a constant input there and it is possible to show that this system is GES and converge to its unique equilibrium point $S^*$ if $A$ is Schur stable; i.e. all its eigenvalues lie in the unit disc. The converse is true under some controllability condition.

In particular, the stationary solution is given by

$$
S^* = \sum_{i=0}^\infty A^iE\Sigma E^T (A^T)^i
$$

This value defines a ball where the state of the system will belong to in the long-run in a mean-square sense. The size of that ball depends on how noisy your noise is (i.e. how big your covariance is), the input matrix $E$, and the stability properties of your system. If some eigenvalues of $A$ are close to the unit circle, then the sum will converge slowly to zero, which will yield a larger value for $S^*$.

The above analysis also implies that

$$
\mathbb{P}(||x(k)||_2^2\ge c)\le\dfrac{\mathrm{trace}(S(k))}{c}
$$

where we used Markov's inequality. That gives an idea of what is happening at the level of the sample-paths.

Comment: Hi KBS, thanks for your comment! I suppose this prove the system is (neutrally) mean square stable, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert^{2} ] = \delta < \infty$. But you state "This value [...] will belong to in the long-run". However, since Gaussian noise is unbounded, we can never guarantee this: in fact, as $k \to \infty$ we are guaranteed that $\boldsymbol{x}(k)$ leaves this ball infinitely often. That's kind of the gist of my struggle (see also my other comment). Sorry if I'm seeing overly nitpicky, I just need a very formal argument, but thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are confusing stability notions at the level of the sample-paths (i.e. in terms of the value of the state) and the stabiliy notions at the moment level. Those are different stability notions and you cannot just use one to state something for the other without additional arguments. You seem to want something that you cannot have. You have a system, it behaves in a certain way, that's it.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see what you mean, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For stochastic systems one normally looks at statistical properties, such as the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and variance. In this case it can still be shown that the expected value of the state $y(k)=\mathbb{E}(x(k))$ of your stochastic system is still globally exponentially stable (GES):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x(k+1)) &= \mathbb{E}(A\,x(k) + E\,w(k)) \\
 &= A\,\mathbb{E}(x(k)) + E\,\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(w(k))}_0
\end{align}

So

$$
y(k+1)=A\,y(k)
$$

is GES if $A$ is Schur.

---

However, having the expected value of the state GES is not useful for a stochastic system if the variance is not bounded or too large. The variance for a [Gaussian random vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is often indicated with a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which is defined as

$$
S = \text{var}(x) = \mathbb{E}((x-\mathbb{E}(x))(x-\mathbb{E}(x))^\top).
$$

The corresponding probability density function of the Gaussian random vector $x$ is given by

$$
f(x) = \frac{\exp(-\frac12 (x-\mu)^\top S^{-1} (x-\mu))}{\sqrt{(2\,\pi)^n |S|}},
$$

with $\mu=\mathbb{E}(x)$ and $|S|$ the determinant of $S$.

Under the assumption that the distribution of the initial conditions $x(0)$ are also normal, with covariance $S(0)=\text{var}(x(0))$, and each sample of $w(k) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ are uncorrelated, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(x(0)\,w(k)^\top) = 0\ \forall\ k$ and $\mathbb{E}(w(j)\,w(k)^\top) = 0\ \forall\ j\neq k$, then the evolution of the covariance matrix $S(k)=\text{var}(x(k))$ can be shown to be

$$
S(k+1) = A\,S(k)\,A^\top + E\,\Sigma\,E^\top.
$$

So the state of the stochastic dynamical system will remain normally distributed, satisfying $x(k) \sim \mathcal{N}(y(k),S(k))$. Since the probability density function associated with this distribution never completely vanished means that $\|x(k)\|$ has no upper bound, although the probability will drop quickly when sufficiently large bounds are picked.

When the involved matrices $A$, $E$ and $\Sigma$ are constant and $A$ is Schur, then over time $S(k)$ will tend towards a constant covariance matrix obtained by solving the following [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)

$$
A\,X\,A^\top - X + E\,\Sigma\,E^\top = 0,
$$

with $\lim_{k\to\infty} S(k) = X$. This $X$ can also be expressed as

$$
X = \sum^\infty_{k=0} A^k E\,\Sigma\,E^\top (A^\top)^k,
$$

but normally other methods of numerically calculating $X$ are used.

Comment: I know that you just gave an example but this is not being GES for a stochastic, this is called "GES in mean" as there are many concepts of stability in the stochastic setting. Additionally, this result does not mean much as we could have stability in mean but still have terrible sample-paths for the stochastic process. In this regard, it would be also important to look at the evolution of the variance to have a clearer picture of what is really going on.

Comment: Hi Kwin, thanks for your answer: as @KBS pointed out, this is not really what I am after since this is indeed not GES. Recall that the definition that I give, which is the definition of GES, implies $\lim_{t \to \infty} x_{k} = 0$ which is certainly not the case for the stochastic system I mention (in fact, this limit is not even well-defined). Thus, would you happen to have any references of constructive proofs on the stability of stochastic systems?

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel In that case, the state of your system does not converge anywhere in the usual sense due to the (noisy) input. This is also true in the deterministic case, if you have an input that is persistent, your state may not converge anywhere. For systems with inputs, we use other stability notions which you mention in your post.

Comment: @KBS I kind of think that's where my entire struggle is, as the stability definitions, i.e. BIBO stability, finite $L_{p}$-gain ($p \geq 1$) and also ISS all rely on the input being either 1.) bounded or 2.) square integrable. However, Gaussian noise $\boldsymbol{w}(k) \notin L_{2}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}(k) \notin L_{\infty}$ which makes all these definite, to my eyes, completely useless (please correct me if I'm wrong). Thus, is it the correct conclusion to draw that the only stability properties I could use are MSS, GES in the mean and almost surely stable (ASS)?

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel There are also other stability notations such as stability in probability, in distribution, the notation of stochastic stability, etc.

Comment: But why is this true? Isn't the signal space $L_{2}$ defined as the space of signals who are square integrable, i.e. finite energy? This is clearly not the case for Gaussian noise? Do you have any pointers to papers that state "if $w(k)$ is a stochastic process with finite variance then $w(k) \in L_{2}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150998/discussion-between-kbs-and-bart-wolleswinkel).

Comment: @KBS I have updated my answer. But the best one can get for stochastic systems (linear with normally distributed noise) is that the expected value of the state is GES and that the covariance matrix is sufficiently small, but the stochastic state itself has no bound (although the probability will drop quickly when sufficiently large bounds are picked).